# Rendering the periodic table in C++ using SFML

Tags: c++, beginner, c++11, sfml

I have created [this](https://github.com/BrandonStaab/periodic-table/tree/78b269676f825c8c859556ad280e429e5b4d4cfb) as an example. It uses [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) as its core dependency along with JSON for modern C++ to load the elements from a file.

Basically what happens is when an object that contains an instance of `sf::Drawable` is created, its constructor will be responsible for adding it to the draw list.  Its destructor is responsible for removing it from the list.

**I am interested in if this is a good approach to dealing with the objects in my program that will need to be rendered or if I should be extending `sf::Drawable` class directly.**

I am also interested in the overall code quality of the entire project. I am aware of the assignment and copy constructors that do nothing.  I am relatively new to C++ (1 semester).

Drawables.cpp

```
#include "Drawables.hpp"

namespace {
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable>> drawList;
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable>>& getDrawList()
{
    return drawList;
}
```

Element.cpp constructor and destructor

```
#include "Element.hpp"

#include <exception>

Element::Element()
{
    drawable = std::shared_ptr<sf::RectangleShape>( new sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector2f{49, 49}) );
    drawable->setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    getDrawList().push_back(drawable);
}

Element::~Element()
{
    // Remove it's drawable from the drawList
    for(int i = getDrawList().size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if(dynamic_cast<sf::RectangleShape*>(getDrawList()[i].get()) == drawable.get())
        {
            getDrawList().erase(getDrawList().begin() + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Client.cpp draw function

```
void Client::draw()
{
    while(window.isOpen()) {
        window.clear();
        for(std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable> obj : getDrawList()) {
            window.draw(*obj);
        }

        window.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code you've posted here, it's pretty straightforward and I'm able to understand what it does. That's great! I have a few suggestions on how to improve it.

## Named Types

One common complaint about the standard template library and templates in general in C++ is the ridiculously long type names that result from using them. I see that in your code here. It's easily solved by creating new named types that represent the common types you use. For example:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable>>
```

uses 3 types with namespaces. If you did this:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable> sharedDrawable;
```

Then your new type becomes:

```
std::vector<sharedDrawable>
```

Or even better, use the new `using` directive in C++11:

```
using sharedDrawableVector = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<sf::Drawable>>;
```

Or something along those lines.

## Use C++!

You're writing in C++, but you're using older methods of iterating through containers. In the destructor of `Element` you're going through the list manually when you could use a `std::find()` method instead.

## Magic Numbers

In the constructor of `Element` you create a vector with coordinates <49, 49>. What does it mean? What is it? Why <49, 49>? You should create a constant with a name that describes what this represents:

```
const sf::Vector2f kRectOriginVector {49, 49}; // Or whatever it means
```

Then use that in the constructor.

Comment: I will implement the std::find() approach, and I really like the typedef suggestion.  I agree that 49 (the width/height of a "periodic element card") should be stored as a constant along with some other variables in my mock-up.